# Optimization+Geometry Question (hyperplane, ellipsoid, maximal norm)

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Given vector $\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and real symmetric matrices $\boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\boldsymbol{B} \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$. I am trying to find the value $d^*$ defined as:
\begin{equation}
d^*=\max_{\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n} \| \boldsymbol{x} \| \quad s.t. \quad \boldsymbol{x}^T \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} = 0 \,,\, \boldsymbol{x}^T \boldsymbol{B} \boldsymbol{x} = 1
\end{equation}
Assumptions: The matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ is positive semidefinite and the matrix $\boldsymbol{B}$ is positive definite. The matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ has to be degenerate (so that $\boldsymbol{x}^T \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x}=0$ is feasible for non-zero $\boldsymbol{x}$).

Is it possible to characterize $d^*$ based on properties of $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{B}$? Ideally, I am interested in the general case, but if that is hopeless, we can further assume that $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{B}$ are only different in terms of their eigenvalues, i.e. $\boldsymbol{A}=\boldsymbol{V} \boldsymbol{D}_1 \boldsymbol{V}^T$ and $\boldsymbol{B}=\boldsymbol{V} \boldsymbol{D}_2 \boldsymbol{V}^T$, where $\boldsymbol{V}$ is some rotation matrix.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I corrected the problem statement (to "B cannot have zero eigenvalues").

Comment: Which vector norm are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good trick whenever you have optimization problems with two matrices where their eigenvalues play a role is to try to co-diagonalize them to simplify the problem. In the case where one of the matrices is PD and the other is PSD, you can always do that by combining a Cholesky decomposition and an eigenvalue decomposition. Starting from your initial statement:

\begin{equation}
d^*=\max_{\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n} \| \boldsymbol{x} \| \quad s.t. \quad \boldsymbol{x}^T \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} = 0 \,,\, \boldsymbol{x}^T \boldsymbol{B} \boldsymbol{x} = 1
\end{equation}
Now let´s take the Cholesky factors of $B$ as $B=R^TR$. Note that these matrices $R$ are full rank and invertible because $B$ is PD, and in fact you could use any square root of $B$ for our purposes. As it was suggested in another answer, it is easier to play with squared norms, so we substitute $\| \boldsymbol{x} \|$ by $x^Tx$. Finally we apply a change of variables  $Rx = y$ and we get:
\begin{equation}
(d^*)^2=\max_{\boldsymbol{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n} \; (R^{-1} y)^T(R^{-1} y) \quad s.t. \quad (R^{-1} y)^T \boldsymbol{A} (R^{-1} y) = 0 \,,\, y^T y = 1
\end{equation}
Half the job is done and now we have the $B$ constraint turned into an identity constraint. Next we do an eigendecomposition of the transformed $A$ as: $R^{-T}AR^{-1} = Q^T\Sigma Q$. Applying a second change of variables $Qy = z$, and using the fact that $z^Tz = y^T y$ because $Q$ is orthonormal, we get:
\begin{equation}
(d^*)^2=\max_{\boldsymbol{z} \in \mathbb{R}^n} \; z^TQR^{-T}R^{-1}Q^Tz \quad s.t. \quad z^T \Sigma z = 0 \,,\, z^T z = 1
\end{equation}
And now we have both constraint matrices in diagonal form! Let´s brand the objective matrix $QR^{-T}R^{-1}Q^T$ as $C$ for clarity. As $A$ was rank deficient, we will have that the first $k$ entries of $\Sigma$ are 0 (or the last $k$, depending on how you have ordered the eigenvalues). The only way for the constraint $z^T \Sigma z = 0$ to be satisfied is if $z$ is non-zero **only** on those $k$ entries, so we know that the entries from $k+1$ to $n$ are 0 and we can forget about them. The problem reduces to the first entries of $z$, labeled $\hat{z}$ and we get:
\begin{equation}
(d^*)^2=\max_{\boldsymbol{\hat{z}} \in \mathbb{R}^k} \; \hat{z}^T C_{1:k,1:k}\hat{z} \quad s.t. \quad  \hat{z}^T \hat{z} = 1
\end{equation}
And this problem is simply an eigenvalue problem on the upper left $k$-by-$k$ corner of $C$, where $d^*$ is the largest eigenvalue of that submatrix. If you were interested in the optimum vector $x$ too, you can zero-pad $\hat{z}$ to get $z$ and then undo the change of variables. If that´s not the case, you only need to get $R$, $Q$ and then compute $\lambda_{max}(Q_{1:k,1:n} R^{-T}R^{-1} Q^T_{1:k,1:n}) = \lambda_{max}(Q_{1:k,1:n} B^{-1} Q^T_{1:k,1:n})$, where $Q_{1:k,1:n}$ is the nullspace of $R^{-T}AR^{-1}$. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! This was indeed very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea: I'm disregarding the $A$ constraint since for a non-zero $\mathbf{x}$ it requires $\det(A)=0$ and nothing more.

So we are left with the second constraint. Since $B$ is real symmetric then $U^TBU=D$, for some orthogonal matrix $U$ and diagonal matrix $D$. Moreover, since $B\succ 0$ we know that all the diagonal elements of $D$ are positive, and they are the eigevalues of $B$.

Now, since we want to maximize $\|\mathbf{x}\|$, which is non-negative, this is equivalent to maximizing $\|\mathbf{x}\|^2$. Let's make a change of variables $\mathbf{x}=U\mathbf{y}$, where U is some orthogonal matrix. Then the objective function to maximize is $\|U\mathbf{y}\|^2\overset{(*)}{=}\|\mathbf{y}\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2$, where (*) comes from the fact that $U$ is orthogonal. For the constraint we have $\mathbf{x}^TB\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y}^TU^TBU\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{y}^TD\mathbf{y}=\sum_{i=1}^n d_iy_i^2$.

Now the problem takes the form $$\max_{y_i}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2 \\ s.t. \sum_{i=1}^n d_iy_i^2$$

To solve this problem we look for the minimum diagonal element $d_{\min}$. Let's sssume index $j$ has the minimum value. Then set $y_j=d_j^{-1}$ and $y_i=0,\; \forall i\neq j$.

Going back to the original problem, the optimal value $d^*$ is simply the inverse of the minimum eigenvalue of $B$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am not sure how you disregard x^T*A*x=0; this implies x is in Null(A), which in itself is an active constraint. What if the vector induced by the lambda_min of B is orthogonal to Null(x)? Then I think you should look at other eigendirections of B. Right?

Comment: Then I assume we need to take the minimum eigenvalue of $B$ that corresponds to the zero eigenvalue of $A$, no? That way you have satisfied the two constraints and attained the maximum value, that part will not change. If there is no eigenvector that satisfies the two constraints then the problem is infeasible.

Comment: If A and B can share same eigenvectors, then what you said in your last comment is correct. But if A and B cannot share same eigenvectors, I am not sure; maybe it can be more complicated, and maybe the solution depends on some combination of d_i's (eigenvalues of B in your notation), due to the angle created by d's and the null space of A. I am not sure though.

Comment: I think that the constraints make it very clear: the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$ of $A$ must be an eigenvector of *some* eigenvalue of $B$ (which we know will not be $0$, since $B$ is PD). Otherwise there is no way to satisfy both constraints. There's no way around it, it basically means that the feasible set is empty.